# Multiple scenes in VR mode and different cameras

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, react-xr

I'm trying to implement [this fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-viewcube-py4db) in an XR environment.

In the fiddle, the second scene is fixed to the screen, but not with the oculus/player camera...

Does anyone have a solution to making a scene or an object always on the top right corner of an oculus? I suppose there is a mistake with the size and camera but cannot find what...

I'm not sure, I broke my brain, it's my first step in XR...

Portal Second Scene Code :

```js
function Viewcube() {
  const { gl, scene, camera, size } = useThree()
  const virtualScene = useMemo(() => new Scene(), [])
  const virtualCam = useRef()
  const ref = useRef()
  const [hover, set] = useState(null)
  const matrix = new Matrix4()

  useFrame(() => {
    matrix.copy(camera.matrix).invert()
    ref.current.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix(matrix)
    gl.autoClear = true
    gl.render(scene, camera)
    gl.autoClear = false
    gl.clearDepth()
    gl.render(virtualScene, virtualCam.current)
  }, 1)

  return createPortal(
    <>
      <OrthographicCamera ref={virtualCam} makeDefault={false} position={[0, 0, 100]} />
      <mesh
        ref={ref}
        raycast={useCamera(virtualCam)}
        position={[size.width / 2 - 80, size.height / 2 - 80, 0]}
        onPointerOut={(e) => set(null)}
        onPointerMove={(e) => set(Math.floor(e.faceIndex / 2))}>
        {[...Array(6)].map((_, index) => (
          <meshLambertMaterial attachArray="material" key={index} color={hover === index ? 'hotpink' : 'white'} />
        ))}
        <boxGeometry args={[60, 60, 60]} />
      </mesh>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} intensity={0.5} />
    </>,
    virtualScene
  )
}
```

To summarize, I would like to display something fixed in the top-right corner of the oculus view, even when moving head, but I am stuck...